# Can a TWRP Wipe Delete SD Card Data That I've Explicitly Excluded?

Tags: external-sd, lineageos

I've got several years of experience rooting, flashing, and even recovering Android phones from severe hangups, but today I'm befuddled as to why I seem to have lost all of my data on the external SD card of a Samsung Galaxy Note 2 (GT-N7100) running LineageOS 14.1 (t03g).

Is the file system for an Android phone somehow integrated with the file system of the SD card such that a System wipe would affect the SD card? If so, then I guess there must be a difference between an SD card formatted on my PC as opposed to having it formatted in the phone itself whereby deleting/wiping the phone's System volume can also cause the SD card to be wiped. I've never had this happen before and the only difference I can recall is that this time I had formatted this SD card on the phone instead of doing it on the PC.

**WHAT I DID:**
I made sure to copy all the data files that I wanted to keep onto the SD card (/external_sdcard) using the File Manager in TWRP 3.0.2 before wiping everything on the phone except the card (I chose to wipe Data, System, Cache, and Dalvik). I was getting ready to flash LineageOS ROM (t0lte) on the phone from the SD card. However, it appears that all the files I had dutifully transferred to the SD card are no more! When I visit /external_sdcard via TWRP, everything's gone! I took the card out and checked it on my PC and indeed, the PC says the card needs to be formatted!

Did I miss something? Did I inadvertently forfeit my SD card data by wiping the phone the way I did?

Comment: I have the same device though not in active use and I flashed several ROMs. This never happened to me unless you inadvertently chose the option to wipe extSD (if there is such a setting)

Comment: Reading again, you said you excluded ext. SD so it shouldn't have happened, unless you thought you did but didn't

Comment: I am 100% sure I excluded the Micro SD Card option.

Comment: Then it's a freak thing. Nothing as expected. You can repeat it to test

Comment: I'd say, next time you come across an issue like this, do not reboot but check and backup the TWRP logs. This might still be relevant regarding that: https://rootzwiki.com/topic/24120-how-to-get-a-log-from-twrp/

Comment: But after moving my files to /external_sdcard, I even went back and confirmed they had been placed there by navigating to that folder and its subfolders with the TWRP File Manager. They were there! I even rebooted once back into the existing installation of LineageOS and saw my internal file storage space had increased dramatically because I had moved the files over to the SD card. Everything looked good. I'm not giving up on this SD card yet! I'll see what I can recover with the SanDisk data recovery utility.